# Scientific Researcher Visa Application Letter

Tags: ireland, working-visas

I have been offered a researcher position at a university in Ireland, and I preparing to apply for a researcher visa. One of the required documents is a letter of application. The letter of application should contain the following information:

- outlining your reason for wanting to come to Ireland,
- giving details of any members of your family who are currently in Ireland, or any other EU Member State,
- giving details of how long you intend to stay in Ireland,
- giving details of where you intend to stay while you are in Ireland,
- undertaking that you will observe the conditions of your visa, that you will not become a burden on the State, and that you will leave the State on the expiry of your permission to remain.

Has anyone here written such a letter before? Is there a template for such a letter? And as I have not yet found an accommodation, would it be a proper answer to write that I still did not find a house? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Did you ask the university for advice?  It's likely they have an office devoted to visas and related issues for international visitors.

Comment: @NateEldredge They do have one, but due to Christmas it won't open until the 14th of January 2019.

Comment: It looks like you have a workable outline right there in the bulleted points.

Answer (score 1):

The Irish visa process for academic research positions is *very* different from other visa types, in that most of the process is completed directly by the research institution rather than by government agencies. I suspect you've already been told that by the (now-reopened) office, but for future readers: You'll work with the university, not with INIS, and the university will handle the documentation on their side and tell you specifically the documents they need from you.